# Merging Aliases in a JOIN?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM `product` left join category on product.category_id = category.id
```

The above join works, but both tables have a title field. The above only gives me one title field from one of the tables.

Im aware I can do aliases:

```
SELECT product.title as pTitle, category.title AS cTitle
```

But I want to have them under the same name so in PHP i can access them as $row['title']

How can this be achieved? (in SQL statement not in PHP)

Comment: Could you assign different values to one variable at the same time? I think it is the same

Comment: Im not sure what you mean?

Comment: *I want to have them under the same name*. Means what? You want to merge the content?

Comment: Yes merge the content.

Comment: And how exactly? What would the result look like?

Comment: all titles would be under title

Comment: product has title A and category B. What would be the merged result?

Comment: You would have 2 rows, A and B under title column

Comment: I don't get it. I recommend you add example data and expected output to your question...

Comment: I want both titles to come out as one field .

Comment: FYI, PHP will overwrite the value with the last element with the same name. Use two names and implement the logic you need in the while/for/whatever loop reading the rows or solve it in SQL (COALESCE, ISNULL, CASE-WHEN, CONCAT) and use one alias.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if you could publish sample data and expected results but maybe something like this will do

```
   SELECT p.title as title , p.everything else , c.everything other than title  FROM `product` p
    left join category c on product.category_id = category.id

    union

    SELECT c.title as title , p.everything other than title , c.everything other than title  FROM `product` p
    left join category c on product.category_id = category.id
```

Answer (score -1):

You can concatenate the second column to the first:

`SELECT CONCAT(product.title, ' ', category.title)  AS Title`